# WooCommerce Subscription with Stripe Gateway

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments, recurring-billing, woocommerce-subscriptions

I have set-up a WooCommerce Subscription with Stripe Gateway. First payment for subscription is working fine, but automatic recurring billing/payment Monthly is not working with stripe, I also noticed that on the Woocommerce->Subscriptions total columns says "Via Manual Renewal" instead "Credit Card" or Stripe.

Can anyone provide me solution for this issue?

[image]

Comment: Try this free plugin. It's working fine https://wordpress.org/plugins/xa-woocommerce-subscriptions

Answer (score 2):

The subscriptions plugin may be in staging mode. This can happen if the domain of the site changes.

Go to *WooCommerce* > *System Status* and check the value of *Subscriptions Mode* under the *Server Environment* section.

[image: Screenshot of a live subscription mode]
[image: Screenshot of a staging subscription mode]

When the subscriptions plugin is installed, it saves the current domain of the site. If this domain changes in the future, the subscriptions plugin will automatically enable staging mode to prevent duplicate payments. When this happens you will see a warning in the admin:

[image: Screenshot of duplicate site warning in subscriptions plugin]

If you click *Quit nagging me*, the warning will be hidden but you will not get another chance to re-enable the automatic payments.

To show that warning message again, you'll need to reset the value of an option in the database. Set the value of `wcs_ignore_duplicate_siteurl_notice` to `false` in the `wp_options` table.

A faster way is to go to the *All Settings* page in your WordPress admin (`/wp-admin/options.php`), and reset it there.

See the WooCommerce Subscriptions documentation for more information: [How Does Subscriptions Handle Staging Sites and Migrations?](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions-handles-staging-sites/).

Answer (score 1):

I know this old but this might help somebody.

That method by woocommerce did not work for me (https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions-handles-staging-sites/#section-4).

What did work was changing another option in wp_options: wc_subscriptions_siteurl.

I changed the value to my current URL and it changed Subscriptions from Staging to Live, and all "Via Manual Renewal" messages were changed to "Via Credit Card (Stripe)" or "Via Paypal".